# Responsive one page div images

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am trying to make a responsive one page layout for a wordpress landing page I am preparing. The HTML code I am using is this:

```
<section id="panel-3" class="pf-fp" data-img="001.jpg">
 <article>
  <h1>Welcome #1</h1>
  <nav> Item 1 / Item 2 / Item 3 </nav>
 </article>
 <img src="001.jpg"/>
</section>
<section id="panel-5" class="pf-fp" data-img="002.jpg">
 <article>
  <h1>Welcome #2</h1>
  <nav> Item 1 / Item 2 / Item 3 </nav>
 </article>
 <img src="002.jpg"/>
</section>
...
<section id="panel-9" class="pf-fp" data-img="003.jpg">
 <article>
  <h1>Welcome #n</h1>
  <nav> Item 1 / Item 2 / Item 3 </nav>
 </article>
 <img src="003.jpg"/>
</section>
```

Each section is defined as a block element with the following css on .pf-fp:

```
.pf-fp {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
}

.pf-fp article {
 z-index:1;
 position: absolute;
 left:0; right:0; bottom:0 top:0;
 display:block;
 color: white;
}

.pf-fp img {
 z-index:0;
 position:absolute;
 left:0; right:0; bottom:0 top:0;
 display:block;
}
```

the problem is when I am trying to resize the screen, it becomes image+white background due to .pf-fp's height:100%; and the responsiveness of img. How do I achieve to have the one section per viewport on desktop - tablet - phone? even if it means to "blow up" the image a bit to fit in the viewport?

Comment: This is a 100% HTML + CSS issue. Please show your actual rendered HTML, not your PHP.

Comment: I edited it to reflect a real case scenario.I think though it needs to be visually shown so I will post images.

Comment: You may want to consider using CSS backgrounds for your images and eliminate all the absolute positioning.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=full+cover+css+images

Comment: I've used backstretch too (found it this morning), but it distorts the image. But then I used the background-size: cover option so it's ok, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Responsive Design with the size of the screen you want to treat

@media only screen and (min-width : 1550px){}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1449px){}

Comment: I've actually solved it using display:table / display:table-cell directives and a slightly different layout. It's really helpful in 100% height divs.